# Twig do not render anything

Tags: twig, rendering

Within last two days I was working at the office with PHP project with Twig installed through Composer. It worked fine on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. I pushed code into repo to be pulled at home to work with on weekend.

But when I launched the project at home (OS X with latest Homebrew PHP 7) I found out that Twig did not render any content - if I look at page source it do not contain anything. Just an empty page.
I tried `{{ dump() }}` trick - same result.

I tried to debug `TwigEnvironment::render()` call: everything looks great - correct template file consumed, cache is properly built with correct code in it, etc.

The only case I managed to render something is the first Basic API Usage example at [Intro page](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/intro.html#basic-api-usage) when template is a PHP array in fact.
Any ideas what's the problem with Twig?

Comment: how do you pass the content to twig? show some code :)

Comment: did you check the php's error log?

Comment: Just right posting the message I set breakpoint at the end of TwigEnvironment::render() and use ob_get_contents() in PhpStorm console  and it dumps good HTML code into console right as it should be. But it do not outputs on the page!

Comment: error log is extremely clean with E_ALL

Comment: for debugging purposes i created empty project with template <h1>Hello world</h1>
{{ dump() }} . And Twig outputs nothing while ob_get_contents() at the end of render() method is correct.

Comment: Guys, looks like I'm the most stupid phper in the world  - i forgot to echo render() result. Just $twig->render() . Sorry, guys, for taking your time.